# Is there any restriction (in terms of A, E, C & M) on default angular directives?

Tags: angularjs

I've just started with Angular and would like to know if there are any restrictions on the default angular directives. If not, can we override default angular directives and put some restrictions?

I need to create an app and I don't want anyone to invoke directives using "class", "comments" or "element". Can I apply this restriction in my angular apps.

Comment: Instead of restricting, why don't you allow based on type you specify, assuming attribute `A` in your case. This will allow directive to be called only as attribute.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) as asked.  Not only are there too many "default" directives to make a blanket statement about, but certain directives require operating this way, while others provide alternatives.  "I don't want anyone to..." doesn't give any information about what you *really* are trying to accomplish, or which directives you might be concerned with.  And if you feel like you have to modify angular to protect yourself from your programmers, you have other issues anyway.

Comment: Actually I've just started learning Angular and was wondering about this. Definitely I don't have any use case as of now but I thought it might be good to know if this situation arises. Thanks for the detailed information. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**I don't think there are some existing flags or options that you can use to do put such restriction on built-in angular directives.**

If there are such options, it should be on `$compileProvider`. But I think you may try to decorate the directives to put such restriction, see [Decorate Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) example in augularjs documents. Even this decorator method works, to get what you want, you need to decorate each of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the configuration for a directive, you can specify `restrict: 'A'` to enforce your particular directive to be only processed as an attribute.